# Count up to a number x - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 100 records, I have to count up to 50 and from 51 to delete the other 49

```
//Start the session
session_start();

//Include connection
include 'connessione.php';

//Query to get stuff from database
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

//Get results
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

//Make that into a JSON array
$results = json_encode( $results );

//Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
$fileName = 'backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
$file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
fwrite( $file, $results );
fclose( $file );

//Delete the rows that you just backed up
$query_delete = "DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
mysqli_query( $connessione, $query_delete );
```

?>
so I pull out the last 50 but if I had to count to A and eliminate from B onwards?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: <mysql>  XOR <sql-server>

Comment: You want to delete the 50 oldest records in table?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher the intent is to create a dynamic query that has 100 records, accounts up to the first limit (50) each time, and delete from 51 to 100 (which are the + older ones), backup in a file and the one I already have

Comment: Just to check, in short, if you have `54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48` and you run this script, you want to backup `52, 51, 50` and delete `49, 48`?

Comment: @HarveyFletcher sorry I was wrong to write from 1 to 50 which are the oldest, are deleted and backed up, from 51 to 100 remain in the db, creating an infinite loop, for which the first 50 of the 100 that will be the oldest will be always backup and the future 51 to 100 remain in the db

Comment: what happens if you change `DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50` to `DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50`

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Fantastic!!!! leaves the last records in the db, deleting the old ones and backups

Comment: @user11317164, I have added this as an answer

Comment: @HarveyFletcher but, it cancels me the old one but makes me the backup of the last record

Comment: @user11317164, I don't understand what you mean, please try again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
delete
from (select nm.*,
             row_number() over (order by id desc) as seq
      from nametable nm
     ) nm
where seq > 500;
```

By this way, it will delete all initial record starts from `501`.

Comment: i don t know why but not work, what is? nm.*? - my value into db id, name,email,psw

Comment: Order by asc or seq <= 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

to this query

```
DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50
```

> user has asked for how to fix other issue, inform

```
...your code above

$results = json_encode( $results );

//Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
$fileName = 'backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
$file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
fwrite( $file, $results );
fclose( $file );

//Delete the rows that you just backed up, but only if there are 50 or more.
if( sizeof( json_decode( $results, true ) ) >= 50 ){
    $query_delete = "DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50";
    mysqli_query( $connessione, $query_delete );
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191333/discussion-on-answer-by-harvey-fletcher-count-up-to-a-number-x-sql). Please make sure that you have [edit]ed the answer to include all relevant information!