# Delete records from the database and save them to a file - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Yes, as my question asks, I need to delete records and the same records that I deleted save them dynamically in a file

I can only view or delete them

```
<?php

    session_start();

    include 'connessione.php';

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    $query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

    ?>
    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

    <?php echo $row['id'] ;?>

    <?php } ?>
```

understanding this process I am able to delete data in my db but keep a local copy just in case

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That query won't run on both.)

Comment: @jarlh mysql with phpmyadmin, build in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save these results in a JSON array.

```
<?php

    //Start the session
    session_start();

    //Include connection
    include 'connessione.php';

    //Get user ID
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    //Query to get stuff from database
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    $query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

    //Get results
    $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    //Make that into a JSON array
    $results = json_encode( $results );

    //Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
    $fileName = 'backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
    $file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
    fwrite( $file, $results );
    fclose( $file );

    //Delete the rows that you just backed up
    $query_delete = "DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    mysqli_query( $connessione, $query_delete );

?>
```

for example, if your table looks like this:

```
| id | name | email_address |
|----+------+---------------|
| 1  | dave | dave@test.com |
| 2  | emma | emma@test.com |
| 3  | mark | mark@test.com |
+----+------+---------------+
```

your backup file will look like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"dave","email_address":"dave@test.com"},{"id":2,"name":"emma","email_address":"emma@test.com"},{"id":3,"name":"mark","email_address":"mark@test.com"}]
```

Comment: backup file work great but not delete records in my table

Comment: yes and this work very perfect, but in the second part of the script nothing is delete from my table

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PSW/home.php on line 31

Comment: @user11317164, I have fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: this generated error:   $query_delete = "DELETE FROM utenti ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
    mysqli_query( $query_delete );

Comment: I had accidentally written `mysqli_query( $query_delete );` and not used the connection `mysqli_query( $connessione, $query_delete )`

Comment: now if u can I have only 1 more question, in this case I delete all my record in a table, but if I have for example 100 record and I want count to 50 and delete to 51 to 100, how can make this?

Comment: Please raise new question then put link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535799/count-up-to-a-number-x-sql

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can save them in file before just delete records.